# SQL Enquiry for exists in every set

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to use SQL to extract values that exist in every set.

Table:

```
+------------+
!ID!Set !Word!
+------------+
!1 !I1  !ABC !
!2 !I1  !DEF !
!3 !I1  !GHI !
!4 !I2  !ABC !
!5 !I2  !LMN !
!6 !I2  !DEF !
!7 !I3  !ABC !
!8 !I3  !GHI !
!9 !I4  !ABC !
!10!I4  !ABC !
+------------+
```

Result:

```
+---+
!ABC!
+---+
```

select ..... Gives 'ABC' because it exists in set I1, I2, I3 and I4 and there aren't any other sets.

I'm after the fastest statement in MYSQL - appreciate your help.

Answer (score 5):

Here is one method:

```
select word
from t
group by word
having count(distinct set) = (select count(distinct set) from t);
```

Note:  The `count(distinct word)` is only needed because duplicates are present in the data.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a80fb/9) is the SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the (correct) quick answer.

I had oversimplified my question, which I have now edited, and the answer would now not work.

Comment: First, the answer does still work, so I don't understand your comment.  However, changing a question in such a way that invalidates answers is rude.  You should, instead, ask another question.  However, despite your intentions, this is still a correct answer.

Comment: Apologies Gordon. I had given you an up vote and acknowledged your correct answer before changing my question. And had debated whether to ask an almost identical question before changing.

The answer does not work though.

Apologies again. In retrospect, I realise that altering the question was poor practise.

Comment: Gordon - this actually does fail with the duplicate. The reason being you are counting ABC five times vs. distinct set only 4. You can see for yourself here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a80fb/9.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it this way using CONCAT:

```
SELECT word
 FROM t
 GROUP BY word
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(set, word)) =
 (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT set) FROM t)
```

Tested here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a80fb/9.